# How do you call a function that has arguments within a case statement?

Tags: linux, bash

I just had a question about case statements and functions with variable input.

When using a case statement, it looks for the statement exactly as stated, as I'd expect here:

```
#!/bin/bash
backupdir="$HOME/backups"
bud () {
# Performs a backup on the directory specified by user input.
if [ ! -d "${backupdir}" ]; then
mkdir -p "${backupdir}"
fi
tar -czvf "${backupdir}/$1.tar.gz" "$2"
logger "Created backup of $1."
sleep 10
}
read -r cmnd
case $cmnd in
bud) bud "$1" "$2";;
esac
done
```

It's impossible to set $1 and $2 via user input because it changes what the case statement would be looking for.

```
read -r cmnd
case $cmnd in
bud*) bud "$1" "$2";;
#--^
esac
```

But in this example, I can type more than one argument and have the case still be executed, but it also assumes that the arguments are part of the case statement.

How can I call a function from a case statement and still pass on variable input?

Comment: Either read multiple variables, e.g., `read  cmnd arg1 arg2` or `read -a` to read an array. See `help read` for details.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! I just checked it out and can't believe I missed it. Thank you Glenn!